# How to code /back command Python telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am working on a telegram bot that simply navigates you through scenario asking different questions, and I want a user to be able back any time to precious step. I came up with giving a value of the position, which is a simple variable. But it did not work and I have no other idea, may be someone can look at my code and figure out what I am doing wrong or may be any other solution?

Thank you in advance!

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("Token")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
   menu = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
   menu.row('Chat')
   menu.row('Not today')

   bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Hi there!', reply_markup=menu)
   position = 0
   return (position)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
   if message.text == 'Chat':
      main_menu_1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
      main_menu_1.row('Good')
      main_menu_1.row('Bad')

      bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'How are you today?', reply_markup=main_menu_1)
      position = 1.1
      return (position)

   elif message.text == 'Good':
      sub_menu_1_1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
      sub_menu_1_1.row('How are you?')
      sub_menu_1_1.row('Bye')

      bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'I am glad for you', reply_markup=sub_menu_1_1)
      position = 2.1
      return (position)

   elif message.text == 'Bad':
      sub_menu_1_2 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
      sub_menu_1_2.row('Alright')
      sub_menu_1_2.row('Why?')

      bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'I dont care)', reply_markup=sub_menu_1_2)
      position = 2.2
      return (position)

   elif message.text == 'Not today':
      main_menu_2 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
      main_menu_2.row('Not in a mood')
      main_menu_2.row('You are just a machine')

      bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Why not?', reply_markup=main_menu_2)
      position = 1.2
      return (position)

   elif message.text == 'Not in a mood':
      sub_menu_2_1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
      sub_menu_2_1.row('Its all good')
      sub_menu_2_1.row('See you')

      bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Sorry to hear that(', reply_markup=sub_menu_2_1)
      position = 2.4
      return (position)

   elif message.text == 'You are just a machine':
      sub_menu_2_2 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
      sub_menu_2_2.row('Not funny')
      sub_menu_2_2.row('Funny')

      bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'You are just a human', reply_markup=sub_menu_2_2)
      position = 2.5
      return (position)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['back'])
def handle_back(message):
   if position.handle_text == 0:
      bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'You are in the main menu already', reply_markup=main_menu)
   elif 1 >= position < 2:
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'You have returned to the main menu',reply_markup=main_menu)
   elif 2 >= position < 3:
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'You have returned to a submenu', reply_markup=main_flavor_menu)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using back command you have to use back button and rewrite the code logic of that way